# How to calculate gain of opamp with Max446 chip?

Tags: amplifier, audio

I just wondering how do you calculate the gain of the amplifier in a circuit like this:[image: MAX446 CHIP]

I am familiar with gain calculation on non-inverting and inverting opamp but am having trouble with this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a non-inverting op-amp with a pass band filter and a DC offset cancellation.

The formula is

> Av = 1 + R2 / R1

Where the resistor are the 100k and 10k, so you would get a gain of 11.

- The first group with 1 cap and 2 1Mohm resistor are a high pass filter and decoupling.
- The 100pF below the chip is a low pass filter.
- The 1uF below the 10k resistor is there to remove DC offset.

Comment: so that means that it will always have a 2.5v input?

Comment: If the input bias current is zero (the input ESD structures have low leakage, and the input transistor is JFET or MOSFET), then YES.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf wouldn't that mean that the output will always be 27.2V?

Comment: That's the purpose of the 1uF cap, to remove DC offset, so only the signal will be amplified. I guess this is a solution to be able to use a single rail supply. The output cannot be higher than the opamp supply voltage.

Comment: @Damien so just to be clear this circuit can be used to amplifier the human voice to used in an ADC?

Comment: @ Newbie The gain is 1 + Z(100Kohm || 100pF) / [ Z(1uF) + z(10kohm)] and at DC the Z(1uf) becomes infinite, thus the gain math becomes 1 + 100Kohm / INFINITEY =====> ONE. This ONE makes the DC output always be centered around 2.5 volts.